# How to position an element such that it neatly rests under a wrapped line

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Using CSS, I want to be able to make the buttons move up if there is empty space (due to text wrapping).

The picture below illustrates the problem.  I want the top button to be displayed a few pixels higher, as there is no text *directly* above it.

Instead, it is aligned with the bottom of text-which-is-only-present-on-the-right.

Is there a way of achieving this with CSS (I can change the HTML)?

[image: Bad button alignment]

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
<div class="right">
  <button class="button-primary">Do this...</button>
</div>
<p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<div class="right">
  <button class="button-primary">Do that...</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
div {
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;  
}

p {
  display:inline;
}

.button-primary {   
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <button class="button-primary">Do this...</button>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <button class="button-primary">Do that...</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that sort of works, but the top of the following element (div) is not aligned with the bottom of the button, it's aligned with the bottom of the text.  This leads to inconsistent vertical spacing if some lines are not long enough to push their buttons down the screen.

Comment: I agree with that, perhaps Jiffs answer is better than ;)

Comment: Your updated answer does the job perfectly.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: inline;` for `p` and use `float: right;` for button. do not put your button in paragraph, it's kinda not a valid `html`

```css
p {
    display: inline;
}

.button-primary {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
<button class="button-primary">Do this...</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This has a similar problem to the answer from @NiZa - the following element's top is not aligned with the bottom of the button, it's aligned with the bottom of the text.

Answer (score 1):

without changing your HTML, maybe you have to use the pseudo `::before`:

```css
div, p {display: inline;}

.right {
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
  clear: both;
}

p:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
<div class="right">
  <button class="button-primary">Do this...</button>
</div>
<p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<div class="right">
  <button class="button-primary">Do that...</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Your got the solution.

```css
div{ display:inline;}

.div-2 {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-1">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</div>
<div class="div-2"><input type="button" value="submit"> </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but this has the same problem as the other two answers.  Later elements are aligned with the bottom of the text, not the bottom of the button.